# Adding a link to each opend image in Mootools image gallery

Tags: mootools

What I am trying to do is to add a different link to each opened image in the Mootools image gallery.
According to the codes below, when you click on each small image or thumbnail, the large size image in the  tag gonna be displayed. What I need to do is to again an  tag to this large image opened. So that when the user clicks on the opened image, he would be directed to a new page.

```
    <table>
      <tr>   
        <td>    <a href="img/pic1.png" data-milkbox="milkbox:g1" title="Lorem ipsum...">    <img src="img/pic1a.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />     </a>    </td>
        <td>    <a href="img/pic1.png" data-milkbox="milkbox:g1" title="Lorem ipsum...">    <img src="img/pic1a.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />     </a>    </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

And the demo is here. http://reghellin.com/milkbox/#demo

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The large image will be displayed by the MilkBox script, with all the HTML being controlled by that plugin itself. Therefore, if the plugin doesn't support adding a secondary link to the opened image, you will have to either workaround it or modify the plugin. The latter is not recommended since it will mean you can't update the plugin without merging in your changes.

The only thing I can think of is to make use of the events MilkBox provides (e.g. onFileReady) to hook in some custom code to wrap a link around the large image, but that would again depend on the workings of MilkBox.

Another alternative is look for a similar lightbox plugin that does allow linking of the opened images.